# $L^1$ convergence and continuous functions/transformaton

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Assume you have the following setting:

Let $\mathbb{P}$ a probability measure and a sequence of real-valued random variables with convergence $X_n\stackrel{L^1(\mathbb{P})}{\rightarrow} X$. Assume $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$. Does the following convergence holds:

$f(X_n)\stackrel{L^1(\mathbb{P})}{\rightarrow} f(X)$

If not is it enough to assume that $X_N, X$ or $f$ are bounded? I guess then it is just dominated convergence.

Comment: Why random variables?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but maybe you want to give me hint, that I overcomplicated my notation/problem.

Comment: $X_n$  a sequence of functions $(L_1)$ on unit interval.

Comment: Not in general. $X_n(x)=x\mathbb{1}{(1/n,1]} +\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1/n]}$  converges to $X(x)=x$ in $L_1$, but for $f:x\mapsto 1/x$ $f(X_n)$ does not converge. Here the probability space is $((0,1],\mathscr{B}((0,1]),\lambda)$, the standard Lebesgue space.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you for this nice counterexample. I assume, if we have $f\in C[0,1]$ and we can conclude with dominated convergence?

Comment: @cogitoergoboom You can use dominated/motone convergence; however in this example one can compute all relevant quantities directly.